# How to show form first and execute OnShow after?

Tags: android, forms, delphi, show-hide, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a button that do a Form2.Show, and on Form2 OnShow event I have a lots of processing, but when I press it, it processes all OnShow events before actually showing the form, so how to show the form first and then do all proccessing?

Comment: Does it actually matter? The user will see the form but it will be unusable (because you'll be still blocking the main thread). Move your hard work to a worker thread and show some fancy animation instead.

Comment: @Victoria do you have a Delphi sample of a 'working thread' so I can see it?

Comment: [Here is one](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014_may_background_delphi_android_threads.html) for example. If you're executing that long running operation only once, anonymous thread can be a hot candidate for you (the one created by calling `CreateAnonymousThread` in that article).

Comment: dont know about android but in windows application you can use the onActivate event and write as first line Update; This will show the form and after the Update; you can do all your other code. You will have to use a private field to check it does this only the first time you get into the onActive event. This is a dirty solution also

Comment: If I put an AnonymousThread inside an OnFormShow or OnIdTCPClientConnect event that is considered a 'working thread'? Synchronize blocks the UI Thread?